# Задать размеры fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Вывожу сообщение при нажатии на кнопку с помощью `fancybox`:

```
$.fancybox("Hello, world!");
```

Как задать размер окна?

Answer (score 1):

1. Открываем http://fancybox.net/api
2. Нажимаем cmd+f и набираем "width"
3. profit

   $.fancybox({
       content: "Поиск рулит",
       width: 200,
       height: 100,
       autoDimensions: false
   });

Answer (score 0):

```
$.fancybox({ content: "<div style='width:400px'>Поиск не рулит</div>" });
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте описание кода, ссылки на документацию и поясните, что не так было у Автора вопроса. Не оставляйте код без комментариев.